# How to globally prevent saving to database in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I made a PHP script in Laravel and now I want to show demo to my buyers. Since I don't want them to make any changes to the database, I was wondering if there is a way to globally disable any saving to the database?

Comment: Backup your db,let them change whatever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `BaseModel` that extends Laravel's default Eloquent model class. And all of your applications models extend that `BaseModel` you can add the following to it:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($model)
    {
        return false;
    });
}
```

This will intercept any `creating` or `updating` events from Eloquent.

This may be the technical answer for your question, but ideally just backup your db and restore it after showing to your buyers.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing will be to create a mysql user that hasn't permissions to insert. Use the following mysql statement to create the user and use this user as the user in your database setting. I don't think there's a global method for this in laravel.

```
 GRANT SELECT ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'%’;
```

This way, your user can view everything, but isn't able to save a bit.